# Android Studio All Files are marked Non-project files

Tags: android-studio, flutter, intellij-idea

Suddenly all my files are marked brown (non-project-files)[image]

The Error message looks like this when I start Android Studio:

[image]

All I did was a Flutter update to v1.12.13+hotfix.9, but the error occured just now.

Furthermore, the lib package moved.

Answer (score -1):

Run `flutter clean` then try again it should work then